# Streaming music and video

Tags: android, streaming, android-wifi

How to create an application that will stream music or video from your android device to any device via wi-fi (like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bianor.ams&hl=ru or in iOs AirStream)? Thank you in advance=)